# Difference of backup system for Aurora and Mysql

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have two database, one is Aurora, the other is Mysql

Both settings are `Automated backups Enabled(7 days)`

On `Snapshot` page, there are snapshots on both RDS.

However in `Automated backups` page, only mysql's Current Region backups are listed.

However there is not Aurora's backup.

Why this difference happens? and is it problem?

Comment: May be this helps - https://repost.aws/questions/QUCDckNPCbTTWDNYno6alYVw/why-do-rds-automatic-backups-not-get-listed